# What are the advantages of MERGE over simple IF EXISTS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know what are the advantages of MERGE over simply using IF EXISTS. Which is the suggested approach? Does MERGE performs Update and Insert row-by-row matching conditions? If yes, is it similar to Cursors?

Comment: I really don't think there are any; in fact there are several disadvantages IMHO, [as I pointed out here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069).

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . By total coincidence, I was about to write a merge statement in some code.  After reading your posts and the related ones, I'll stick with the `if exists` form.  At least the race conditions will be obvious (and not being high volume,  concurrency issues are quite unlikely).  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge will give you the option of updating, inserting and deleting data in a target table where is it matched in a source table.  It is a set based operation so is not like a cursor (row by row)

I am not sure how you mean by advantages over 'IF EXISTS', but merge is a useful and flexible way of synchronizing 2 tables

this is a useful resource for merge https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: And for a contrary opinion: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069

Comment: interesting link, I was unaware of those bugs, and will consider them the next time using MERGE is an option, cheers

Answer (score 4):

MERGE combines INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE logic into one DML statement, and therefore is atomic.  If you are doing single row UPSERTS then the advantages are less obvious.  For example, a naive implementation of an UPSERT may look like the following:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 where id=@id)
    UPDATE t1 SET ... WHERE id=@id
ELSE
    INSERT INTO t1 (...) VALUES (...)
```

However, without wrapping this in a transaction, it is possible that the row we're going to update will be deleted between the SELECT and the UPDATE.  Adding minimal logic to address that issue give us this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK) where id=@id )
    UPDATE t1 SET ... WHERE id=@id
ELSE
    INSERT INTO t1 (...) VALUES (...)
COMMIT
```

This logic isn't necessary with the MERGE statement.

There are no comparisons that should be drawn between CURSORS and the MERGE statement.

Comment: Well, be careful about that promise: it is only atomic with specific hints or isolation levels. By default [it behaves like separate statements](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Comment: Quoting from the link "The HOLDLOCK hint was still needed, though, because MERGE otherwise releases the update key lock before the insert". So all MERGE needs is a HOLDLOCK.